# Finding overlapping times from a select statement

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I have a table (timetable) in a database (calendar) which if formatted like so:

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| id |  name  |    day    | startTime | endTime |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | George | Sunday    | 12:00     | 14:00   |
| 2  | Dan    | Monday    | 13:30     | 15:30   |
|  3 | Jeff   | Wednesday | 12:00     | 14:00   |
|  4 | Bill   | Monday    | 13:45     | 15:45   |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Then I have some PHP as follows:

```
  <?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)"
    $result = $con->query($sql);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $array2[] = $row;
    }    

  echo json_encode($array2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

  ?>
```

And that outputs the entire table, as an associated array in JSON format.

I want it to only output the two that clash. There will never be more than two that clash in the database due to the input method, so it only needs to check if there's one clash, and output the JSON for both rows.

I'm not sure where to start. Is it better to do it programatically via PHP, or is there a way to do with with mysql? I was thinking if it's done programatically, maybe two nested for loops and if statements for greater than or less than on the time fields? But seems messy, and I'm thinking there's likely a more clever end elegant solution that I can't think of.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: you can use `<=` and `>=` in mysql. no need to do it in PHP layer. if the columns are `time` field, yes, mysql can understand that format

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *`. Name (and qualify) the columns you want returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with **JOIN** in **SQL** like below:-

To find "any overlap", you compare the opposite ends of the timeframe with each other.

```
SELECT * FROM timetable a
JOIN timetable b 
    on a.starttime <= b.endtime
    and a.endtime >= b.starttime
    and a.name != b.name;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the SQL I ended up using, just in case anyone else is having a similar problem:

`SELECT * FROM timetable a 
JOIN timetable b
on a.startTime <= b.endTime 
and a.endTime >= b.startTime 
and a.id != b.id 
and a.day = b.day 
WHERE b.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4) 
AND a.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`